# Merging DEM with polygons/lines

Tags: qgis, polygon, dem

I want to connect my DEM (digital elevation model) with the map which was divided into polygons/lines. I am analyzing tsunami events in my project. I have the following documents: one of them contains forests/living areas as polygons and buildings as points. The other one is the Digital Elevation Model to which I have applied TIN interpolation by given elevation points. By the possible tsunami heights, I want to analyze which buildings are located in the inundation area or which percentage of the forest was affected. Is it possible to merge them?

Comment: Hi Fidan welcome to GIS SE. People are going to need a lot more detail in order to help you. What do you mean by connect? What is your end goal? Give people some more information to work with :)

Comment: @TeddyTedTed Thank you! sorry for my un-detailed question, it is my bad. I am analyzing tsunami events in my project. I have the following documents: one of them contains forests/living areas as polygons and buildings as points. The other one is the Digital Elevation Model to which I have applied TIN interpolation by given elevation points. By the possible tsunami heights, I want to analyze which buildings are located in the inundation area or which percentage of the forest was affected.I hope that now it is a bit clear:) thanks again and have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Fidan, instead of putting relevant information in a comment, edit your question and put the information in the question. Please look at this explanation to learn how to improve your question. Such improvements make your question more likely to get the help you need. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example